# Django-vote implementation for comment up/down voting system

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am new to Django, and I am trying to implement up/downvotes in a comments app I am building, using django-vote: https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote
for the implementation. However, either I am not understanding the django-vote documentation correctly or my implementation is faulty. I've looked through the source code for django-vote on its github but to no avail.

I've tried tracing back the faults by having the code print to console at each step, and it seems like the django-vote app isnt actually logging the votes. If that is the case I may just try to build another one from scratch, but am not sure.

```
 HTML for the vote buttons:
     <i class=" vote upvote increment fas fa-chevron-circle-up" data-userid ="{{ request.user.id }}" data-commentid="{{ comment.id }}" data-action='UP' ></i>

     <i class="vote downvote increment fas fa-chevron-circle-down" data-userid ="{{ request.user.id }}" data-commentid="{{ comment.id }}" data-action='DOWN'></i>

JS:
$(".increment").click(function(event){
  var v = $(this);
  var action = v.data('action');
  var commentID = v.data('commentid');
  var userID = v.data('userid');
  console.log("vote submitted");
  console.log(commentID);
  console.log(action);
  console.log(userID);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/comments/vote/", 
    data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : '{{ csrf_token }}', commentID: commentID, 
     action: action, userID : userID, }, 
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {

      console.log(data);
     console.log("vote success")},
    error: function() {
      console.log('vote failure')
    }
  });

});
Django view function:
@login_required
@require_POST
def comment_vote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        voting_user = request.POST.get('userID') 
        comment_id = request.POST.get('commentID')
        voteAction = request.POST.get('action')
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_id)

        if voteAction == 'UP':
            comment.votes.up(user_id= voting_user)
        elif voteAction == 'DOWN':
            comment.votes.down(voting_user)
        comment.total_score = comment.calculate_vote_score
        comment.save()
        data = {'user' : voting_user, 'vote' : voteAction,'comment' : comment_id, }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: What are the results of your `console.log`s?

Comment: If the first `console.log` statements show the correct data, can you try adding print statements for each field to your view on django?

Comment: The console logs and the Json dump all give the correct data on both ends, which makes me think the problem is the django-vote plugin or my implementation of it.Just tried print statements in the view function and it is showing the correct data too.

Comment: Did you try using the code below?  I'm not familiar with the vote plugin, but you can always simply increment the `vote` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the following line does, although I see what you want to accomplish:

```
comment.votes.up(user_id= voting_user)
```

Assuming you are actually getting the data in your view, try this:

```
from django.db.models import F

comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_id)
if voteAction = 'UP':
    comment.update(vote_count_column = F('vote_count_column') + 1)
elif voteAction = 'DOWN':
    comment.update(vote_count_column = F('vote_count_column') - 1)
```

where `vote_count_column` is an integer column that holds the vote count.

If that doesn't work, let me know.  I have more ideas.

Comment: I think update() only works on querysets, not individual objects. Incrementing the vote column itself wont work because the votes are actually objects with UP or DOWN action attributes.Im in the middle of just making my own upvote system, but now it seems my js is firing twice for some reason, creating a race condition.